# How to implement trim() method in java by using only substring() method

Tags: java, string

I know this question is quite silly, but in an interview I was told to implement trim() method without using any method from String class except substring() method.

I approached this problem by using toCharArray() and then identifying the first and last valid character of String. But was told not to use toCharArray() method.

Could anyone suggest some approach to do it.

Overriden methods of Objects class are allowed like equals() and hashCode().

Comment: does using `String#equals(..)` count as a method from the `String` class? I assume it would but I want to check b/c it's an overriden method from `Object`

Comment: Hint: `String.indexOf()`

Comment: Can you use a for loop combined with charAt()?

Comment: @biziclop That's in the String class

Comment: Can you use `indexOf()` ?

Comment: @Mshnik equals method can be used.

Comment: can you use a `for` loop, considering that it will call `iterator()` implicitly?

Comment: @Spencer4134 Then the question doesn't make sense. The only way to get any information out of a string is through one of its methods. Of course you can cheat and initialise a `StringBuilder` with it, and then perform the operations on the builder.

Comment: Oh that's right @azurefrog

Comment: That seems like a terrible question. I can think of a way to implement it using only `substring` and `equals`, but it would be a horrible approach. Why force someone to write bad bad code?

Comment: You can't even use `length()`? If that's the case, this is a really, really bad interview question. It's basically asking, "Can you design something so overly complex and inefficient that no one in their right mind would want to maintain it?"

Comment: @resueman Please share your approach.

Comment: It's not a bad interview question imho. It's a though one to get asked, but it's not impossible. It's just to test once answer and logical thinking. Reading the string into some sort of byte buffer and and finding the whitespaces whilest remembering their location and then substringing doesn't seem impossible.

Comment: To be honest with you, I would've just answered: how about no? It's one of those questions that sounds terribly clever but what it really does is force you to think like no developer should think.

Comment: @user3437460 No, only substring() method was allowed from String class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String untrimmed = "  some   string   ";
String trimmed = "";

String innerSpaces = "";
boolean wordBoundary = true;

try {
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        String substr = untrimmed.substring(i, i + 1);

        if (!substr.equals(" ") && !substr.equals("\t") && 
               !substr.equals("\n") && !substr.equals("\r")) {

            trimmed += innerSpaces + substr;
            wordBoundary = false;
            innerSpaces = "";
        }
        else if (!wordBoundary) {
            innerSpaces += substr;
        }
    }
}
catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e)  { }

System.out.println(trimmed);
```

Comment: The `try-catch` is horrible

Comment: There is no other way of knowing when the string ends without knowing its length. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's kind of true, but I think he just misinterpreted the question. Of course he should have access to methods that only *get*  some information about the underlying char array, of the array itself. But I get what you mean...

Comment: Given the ridiculous initial conditions, this is about what I ended up with, too.  However, these sorts of interview questions would make me not take the job.

Comment: _trim_ will also remove newlines.

Comment: Updated to remove newlines and carriage returns.

Comment: @MattClark Yes, but the principle of the solution is the same.

Answer (score 4):

Of course `substring` would be needed for the trimmed result.

Without any method of `String` it would be hard to find possible spaces at both ends.

Remains:

1. Outer handling:

   Some form of

   ```
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*(\\S*)\\s*"); // Pattern not okay
   Matcher m = pattern.matcher(string);
   string = m.matches()? m.group(1) : string;
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   Set<String> set0 = new HashSet<>();
   set0.add(string);
   Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
   try {
       set.add(" " + string.substring(1));
       if (set0.contains(set)) {
           ...
   } catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e) { ... }
   ```
2. Using a method of a super class of String. However there is no one that is not overriden by String itself. Maybe the following would be allowable:

   ```
   CharSequence cs = string;
   // Use cs.charAt or Whatever
   ```

Both seem legalistic solutions. *I would lave to know their solution - or was it an impossible-answer question.*

Comment: This is not a valid answer. The question specifically states that this pseudo-trim method needs to use the `substring` method. While your solution works, it does not follow the requirements of the question.

Comment: It's valid afaik. He said he COULD only use substring, not that it was needed.

Comment: @MageXy The way I read the question, it says you can't use any method except `substring()`. It doesn't say you must use `substring()`. But if they insist, I can get the start and end index of the match group and call a `substring()` on the original string. :)

Comment: This will fail for string like `[space]foo[space]bar[space]` since pattern will accept only `[space]foo[space]` which means that `matches()` will return false so `string` will be the same. You may want to use `Pattern.compile("\\s*(\\S+(\\s+\\S+)*)\\s*");` instead.

Comment: @Pshemo thanks for the correct pattern. I saw the error a bit later too, However I did not want to give such a solution as interview answer without commenting to the interviewer. Probably they forgot to allow `equals` or `internalize` (so one can use `==`)

Comment: For the rest the alternative answer with StringBuilder would be more suitable for real usage.

Answer (score 1):

Hacky, but the question is stupid anyway :

```
public static String trim(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    int start, end;
    for (start = 0; start < sb.length() && Character.isWhitespace(sb.charAt(start)); start++);
    for (end = sb.length() - 1; end > start && Character.isWhitespace(sb.charAt(end)); end--);
    return sb.substring(start, end + 1);
}

System.out.println(trim("   \n \t trim me  \t "));
```

Comment: NICE!! really liked it 1+

Answer (score 0):

You can cheat and instead call `String`s methods indirectly:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(sb);
for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
   char ch = sb.charAt(i);
   ...
}
```

If anyone asks, you aren't calling any methods on `String`, not even `substring()`. `StringBuilder` does it for you. :)

All in all, this is a terrible question, I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

A very inefficient solution, but here it goes.

You said in the comments you *can* use the .equals() method. So here's my elaborate solution:

You know those mileage counters in cars? The ones that go 0000, 0001, 0002... etc.? Mimic that with a char arrayList.

Start with size 1, and go through each character, using `mainString.equals(charArrayList.toString())` to compare it. If you get through all the characters, and no match, increase size by one and repeat. Once you have a match, you can check for whitespace characters at the beginning and end.

Please keep in mind I know this isn't efficient, but it works. Even if it takes a year :)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's not too hard if you start by redefining `length()` and `charAt()` in terms of `substring`... Of course it's inefficient (length now takes `O(n^2)`), but it gets the job done and as a bonus defines both `length()` and `charAt()`

```
  public static int length(String s) {
    for(int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
      try {
        s.substring(i);
      }catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        return i - 1;
      }
    }
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  }

  public static char charAt(String s, int idx) {
    String c = s.substring(idx, idx+1);
    return (char)c.hashCode();
  }

  public static String trim(String s) {
    final int length = length(s);
    int startIndex;
    int endIndex;

    for(startIndex = 0; startIndex < length; startIndex++) {
      char c = charAt(s, startIndex);
      if(! Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
        break;
      }
    }

    for(endIndex = length; endIndex > startIndex; endIndex--) {
      char c = charAt(s, endIndex - 1);
      if(! Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
        break;
      }
    }
    return s.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
  }
```